# Can't figure out how to sort through an array the way I want to

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm working on a permission system. It is basically a role-based system. I have a group table with a many-to-many relationship with a tasks table, and a permissions table to tie them together.

The data would look something like this (tasks table):

```
+-----+--------+---------+----------+
| id  |  task  |  group  |  parent  |
|-----------------------------------|
|  1  |  view  |  news   |          |
|-----------------------------------|
|  2  |  edit  |  news   |          |
|-----------------------------------|
|  3  |  view  | forums  |          |
|-----------------------------------|
|  4  |a forum | forums  |   view   |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

What I'm trying to do is allow each group specific permissions with each page. But when needed, more specificity is available. For example on a forums page, I want to be able to control which group can view/edit posts/delete posts/etc from each individual forum.

This is all working - my problem is how to display this data so that it can be assigned. This is what I want it to look like:

```
News
-- View
-- Edit

Forums 
-- View
---- a forum

-- Edit
---- a forum
```

I just can't wrap my head around how to format this array to do that

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [task] => view
            [group] => news
            [parent] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [task] => edit
            [group] => news
            [parent] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [task] => view
            [group] => forums
            [parent] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [task] => a forum
            [group] => forums
            [parent] => view
        )
)
```

Sorry for the confusing post!

Comment: In my mind that is the important stuff... that way people know what I'm trying to do and what I'm trying to do it with. Better to just get it out of the way now than have to type it in later.

Answer (score 0):

Okay totally reformatting my answer now, as it was a bit ambigious what exactly is NOT working.

First rearrange the array like this:

```
while($result = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    $group = $result['group'];
    foreach($result as $field => $value)
    {       
        $data[$group][$field] = $value;
    }   
}
```

Then you can iterate through it:

```
foreach($data as $group) 
{
    echo $group;
    foreach($group as $task => $value) 
    { 
         if($task == 'parent' && $task != '') { $indent = '----';} 
         else {$indent = '--'; }
         echo $indent,$task;
    }
}
```

All just sketched out of my head, so I hope it works and it is what you want this time.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood my post. I already have that array structure, I want to format it in a tree-like structure like I said in the OP.